# vector string push_back is not working in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, containers

This code snippet receives string, delimiter(space) and vector as argument and splits the string according to delimiter and stores it in vector. It is not storing anything into vector if i use push_back but works if i use [] operator. Can someone explain why push_back is not working?

```
void split(const string & input,char delim,vector<string> & elems){
    stringstream  ss;
    ss.str(input);
    string item;
    int i = 0;
    while(getline(ss,item,delim)){
        //elems.push_back(item);
        elems[i] = item;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
   char delim = ' ';
   vector<string> item(2);
   string input;
   getline(cin,input);
   split(input,delim,item);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I would take an educated guess that your `elems` array is not empty on entry to the function; eg you have declared it with `std::vector<std::string> elems(100);` or the like, so your `split()` code would do `push_back()` to the 101th element onwards.

Comment: should i use push_front()?

Comment: No, you should just not allocate space.

Comment: How will that help? can you elaborate please.?

Comment: Show us how you're calling the function and creating the `vector` you pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've pre-allocated the vector with some size (n), then pushback(item) puts item at index n and resizes the vector to an even larger size. If you know the string count due in, then you should use `elems[i] = item;` anyway after an allocation of size n.

If you don't know the count coming in, but know it's going to be larger than some n, do not pre-allocate. Instead, RESERVE some memory with `elems.reserve(n);`

Then use `elems.push_back(item);`

Answer (score 1):

In the `main` function, please change the declaration of item from

```
vector<string> item(2);
```

to

```
vector<string> item;
```

And change the `split` function to use `push_back`:

```
void split(const std::string & input,char delim, std::vector<std::string> & elems){
    std::stringstream  ss;
    ss.str(input);
    std::string item;
    int i = 0; // no more required unless for some other purpose
    while(getline(ss,item,delim)){
        elems.push_back(item);
        //elems[i] = item;
        i++; // no more required
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the i. It is no longer needed.

Comment: @dmg: yes I agree, but left it as its intention is not fully known and not directly related to the issue.

Comment: @elimad i understand what you are saying, but still what's wrong if we even have vector<string> item(2) , it will just create a vector of size 2 with empty strings as elements and after that keep pushing string in end. Shouldn't that work?