# Store entered values in an array in cpp

Tags: c++

Sry for asking such a "dumb" question, but for some reason my solutions does not work.

I simply want to write a code where the user enters a positive integer **n**. Afterwards the user must enter **n** random integers numbers that are stored in a vector.

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{   
    int n, m;
    std::cin>>n;
    
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        std::cin>>m; 
        vec.push_back(m);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<vec[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

For the input

```
3 1 2 3
```

the above code gives the ouput

```
0 0 0 // instead of 1 2 3
```

What went wrong?

Comment: `std::vector<int> vec(n);` creates a vector with `n` elements then you push `n` more elements to that vector but you only look at the first `n` elements. There must be duplicates somewhere. Use iterators or range-based loops to avoid such mistake completely

Comment: for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177257/vector-string-push-back-is-not-working-in-c

Comment: If you would have outputted `vec.size()`, you would see the error.  You would have seen that `n` and `vec.size()` are not the same.

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't enter n *random* integers, but something like 1 1 1 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following initialization
`std::vector<int> vec(n);`

you are declaring a vector with a size from [0..n]

with this

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    std::cin>>m; 
    vec.push_back(m);
}
```

it will allocate more space to the end of the vector and what you will have is [0..n+n]

to solve this change that loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    std::cin>>m; 
    vec[i] = m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate a vector of size n. But you push past the 'allocated size. Remove the vector allocation and it will work.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thx!

Comment: Not really true. He could still allocate the vector using `vector::reserve`. The problem is that the vector is initialized with `n` elements and he pushes `n` more elements, just like idclev 463035818 says in the comments. "pushing past the allocated size" is also not a thing, as the vector will just resize and allocate more capacity.

Comment: Hello. The issue is about printing only n elements whereas entries have been pushed passed the initial n size.